# CKEditor links wrap the contents of a container individually instead of a container

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm in a situation where I want to use WYSIWYG with CKEditor because of the easy Media integration. However, I'm building a page with some interactive tabs that have markup something like this:

**(#1)**

```
<div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            [[Media markup to insert an image]]
        </div>
        <p class="tab-text">Some text.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            [[Media markup to insert an image]]
        </div>
        <p class="tab-text">Some text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap each of these tabs with a link, this being the desired end result:

**(#2)**

```
<div class="tab-wrapper">
    <a href="/somepage">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab">
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                [[Media markup to insert an image]]
            </div>
            <p class="tab-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/someotherpage">
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                [[Media markup to insert an image]]
            </div>
            <p class="tab-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

If I try to do this in CKEditor, however, I get this:

**(#3)**

```
<div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <a href="/somepage">[[Media markup to insert an image]]</a>
        </div>
        <p class="tab-text"><a href="/somepage">Some text.</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <a href="/someotherpage">[[Media markup to insert an image]]</a>
        </div>
        <p class="tab-text"><a href="/someotherpage">Some text.</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This creates problems with styling and, more importantly, makes some regions of the tab unclickable. What's even more maddening is that *even if I disable rich text and edit the HTML directly* to #3, if I switch back to CKEditor it "corrects" the markup to #2.

Is there any way to change or otherwise prevent this behavior? I still want to use the Media module integration to insert and modify images, so I'm hesitant to simply disable CKEditor and leave it off. I can insert my images, then edit the HTML to insert my link tags properly, then save the page, but it can still break again if I go back to make changes.

I'm currently running CKEditor version 3.6.6.7689, WYSIWYG module 7.x-2.2, Media 7.x-2.0-alpha3, and the latest Drupal 7 core.

Answer (score 1):

The CKEDitor by default restricts the HTML you can use to what it considers *safe* by means of something called the [advanced content filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) (ACF). It is this feature of CKeditor that rejects your HTML-construct.

To change or otherwise prevent this behavior, you must describe the construct you want to allow by using the syntax described in the allowed content rules and assigned the JavaScript variable `config.extraAllowedContent`.

**PS**: If you Google this, you'll often see the following JavaScript suggested to "fix" to CKEDitor removing "unsafe" HTML:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

What the above line does it to turn ACF of completely.  It will allow *any* valid HTML to be inserted.  It is OK to do this for testing and debugging, but it is not recommended that you do this on a production site.

Comment: I'm confused, do you have to assign config.extraAllowedContent somewhere? I set config.allowedContent = true; in ckeditor/edit/Full but that doesn't fix this particular issue. Also Advanced Content Filter is Disabled in those settings.